# Differential equation particular solution 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the particular solution for the differential equation:

$y^{(4)} + y = e^{-x}\sin x$

I know that this equation will become $r^4 + 1 = e^{-x} \sin x$.
And I need some kind of root like $-1$ and $-i$.
But I can't figure out anything else.

Comment: I assume you mean $y^{''''}+y=e^-x\sin x$ (fourth derivative $y^{''''}=y^{(4)}$ instead of a fourth power of $y$).

Comment: Yes @daruma it's is fourth derivate of y

Comment: I don'y know what you mean by the solution of the form @RicardoCavalcanti

Answer (score 1):

### Hint

- Solve the homogenous system $y^{(4)} + y = 0$.
- Find the particular solution by trying particular solutions of the form $Ae^{-x} \cos(x) + Be^{-x} \sin(x)$, then finding the needed values of A and B.
- Add the homogenous solution to the particular solution found.

Comment: So I solved the system, i have A=0 , B=1.

Comment: Did you solve for the homogenous system?

Comment: Well yes I have the roots

Comment: Oh right, you said the roots were $-1$ and $-i$. Then your homogenous solution is $Ce^{-x}+De^{-ix}$, where $C$ and $D$ are arbitrary constants (you can solve for C and D if you are given some initial condition but given how I see no initial conditions, you can likely leave it there.